# Electric guitar buzzing sound electricity

Tags: guitar, sound

My guitar making buzzing sound. I don't know what is happening. Sometimes it making buzzing sound and then its gone and then it comes again. But when i touch a metal part from the guitar ( near to the guitar plug-in / jack ) sound suddenly gone. I couldn't tell you so much , so i post a video to [YOUTUBE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu0dRPyXuGw) so you guys can find out what is happening.

Help me please.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: [pickups-and-selector-switch-stop-buzzing-when-touched](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15878/pickups-and-selector-switch-stop-buzzing-when-touched). _Sometimes_ this is caused by your own body picking up noise from nearby computer screens, fluorescent lights etc.

Comment: Either there is earthing issues with your guitar, or with your home. If its something with guitar, Tim's solution will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that there is an earthing problem with the guitar. All of the metal parts should be electrically joined, often with a braided wire. This puts them all at the same voltage level. Open up the guitar, which on a Strat involves taking strings and scratchplate off, and check that the earth wire joins all of the components. If that sounds scary, you need to find a guitar tech to do the job. Good luck.

Comment: hahah definitely sounds like it. I have so much static in my strat strings that one of the capacitors will occasionally create a popping sound in my signal.